# How to disable "disallowtab" in phpcs inside vscode?

Tags: vscode-extensions, phpcs

I am using vscode editing legacy php code. The phpcs extensions is great in finding potential problems. However, the old code is using tab instead of 4 spaces for indentation. phpcs would report with:

Spaces must be used to indent lines; tabs are not allowedPHPCS(Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowTabIndent.TabsUsed)

Because it is old code, I am not planning to fix all of the tab problem. Is there any way to turn off this rule?

I tried to find phpcs config files, cannot find any. Ideally I can set a globaly, or project-wise, to disable it. Can anybody help?